# Creating a chat screen like whatsapp or telegram with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, android-jetpack-compose, appbar

I am trying to create a chat screen like telegram, whatsapp, etc. using Jetpack Compose. But, I am not able to replicate the exact behavior. The specific part of the functionality that I am not able to emulate is when soft keyboard opens the topbar scrolls off the screen, however,it is static in telegram and whatsapp.
Here is what the main screen looks like: https://disk.yandex.com/i/evEIvPCIJY-8wg
This is the problem : https://disk.yandex.com/i/hC8eC6gpNSiRcw
When the TextField is focused, topAppBar scrolls off the screen.
The Container which has messages has vertical scroll modifier set. Hopefully, somebody can help with this.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ConstraintChat() {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val (appBar, editBox, content) = createRefs()

        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(56.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .constrainAs(appBar) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text("Title", modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall)
        }
        ChatContent(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .constrainAs(content) {
                top.linkTo(appBar.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                bottom.linkTo(editBox.top)
                height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
            })
        ChatEditText(textFieldValue = TextFieldValue(""), onChange = {}, onNewMessage = {},
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(editBox) {
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added custom appbar, because I suspected that the library version might be adding scroll behavior to it. However, the problem still remains. Which means it is not related to that. I got same behavior in the Scaffold composable, so I decided to try Custom composables, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: In the "past", we put `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in the root layout, see https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft

Comment: The issue here is @Preview annotation, because, I had deployed the standalone Composable function to the emulator. If I put the Composable function in setContent lambda of MainActivity, there is no auto scrolling of the appbar.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your manifest to keep TopAppbar and move input above soft keyboard.

Layout

```
@Composable
fun DemoFullChat() {

    val messages = remember { mutableStateListOf<ChatMessage>() }
    val sdf = remember { SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.ROOT) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(0xffFBE9E7))
    ) {

        ChatAppbar()


        val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            state = scrollState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
        ) {
            items(messages) { message: ChatMessage ->

               // Messages here
            }
        }

        ChatInput(
            onMessageChange = { messageContent ->
                messages.add(
                    ChatMessage(
                        (messages.size + 1).toLong(),
                        messageContent,
                        System.currentTimeMillis()
                    )
                )

                coroutineScope.launch {
                    scrollState.animateScrollToItem(messages.size - 1)
                }

            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

You can see full implementation [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Flexible-Chat-Box). It's dynamic chat row library that adjust message status based on message width and message line and sets width of every sibling to longest one using SubcomposeLayout.

Comment: I was already using that flag, but, the issue was @Preview annotation. When I deployed the preview on an emulator or a device, it ignored any value in the manifest. So, I wasted a whole night trying various things, until I decided to put the composable in an activity and test it, that's when it worked. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Comment: Okay, great. You shouldn't waste a lot of time for something that is not properly displaying in preview. At least, library in link might help you to create dynamic chat rows or similar layout like whatsapp. Happy coding